# how can i change default timezone like 'UTC' whole application? Javascript, Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, date, javascript-date

I'm working on a Hotel application and the customers use UTC for communication. I completed mostly and I used everywhere date object like that  => new Date() so before I run the application I want to change my local timezone like UTC and when I create new Date object it has to be UTC format. [![enter image description here]

I tried a lot of things,  I tried tho expend Date object and when create date instance for everyone obejct I return our date instance. I didn't achieve. I have to get zimezone 0 of date object and I cant use any 3pr library.

```
providers: [{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: initializeApp,
  multi: true
}...]

export function initializeApp() {return () => {
const a = Intl.DateTimeFormat()
console.log(a);
Intl.DateTimeFormat(['en-US'], {
  timeZone: 'UTC'
});
console.log(a);};}
```

Comment: Not really sure what your trying to do here, internally all dates in Javascript are UTC.  The part that's locale is how that date is displayed / entered.  IOW: You shouldn't need to be converting anything.

Comment: Just construct your dates from ISO strings with `Z` offset or from `Date.UTC` values, and never use `.toString()` but always `.toUTCString()` (same for the other methods)

Comment: Where are you actually using those `DateTimeFormat`s you construct in `initiatilizeApp`?

Comment: @Bergi Actually, I just wondered what was coming, and because of that, I wrote there. It's an example. I wonder what we can do.

Comment: You can use it to [`format`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format) your `new Date()` object?

Comment: But to answer your titular question, it is impossible to change the "default timezone" that `Date::toString` uses, it's always the system timezone that you do not control. So avoid that method. If you need further help, please show us the parts of your code that actually use `Date` objects and have unexpected outputs.

Comment: @Keith when I create date object like this =>  const a = new Date(); I want to see like that => 'Tue, 09 Jan 2024 18:45:43 GMT' but it looks like that => Tue Jan 09 2024 21:44:54 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)

Comment: @Bergi How it impossible ? Can not I change timezone of Date() Object

Comment: @SelimÜnal No, you cannot, as a `Date` object does not **have** a timezone. It's only some of the methods that interpret the instant in a certain timezone.

Comment: Can I change the data that is coming from a certain time zone? @Bergi I want to make a calculation with utc timezone.

Comment: What do you mean by "*data that is coming from a certain time zone*"? Again, please [edit] your question to show us the part of your code that has problems

Comment: @Bergi just you take care of me. I'm explaining. My project has many "new Date()" objects. I don't want to change them one by one. Before loading the project,. I have to change the timezone, which is coming from computer or browser. For example, ```const a = new Date();
console.log(a); // Thu Jan 11 2024 11:45:42 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
``` it has to be show everywhere like that
```Thu Jan 11 2024 08:45:42 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)```

Comment: Again, you cannot do that! You have to change your code, in every place where you parse or output a date. Ignore what `console.log` is showing you, but use [`a.toUTCString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) instead of the implicit `a.toString()`. There is no other way.

Answer (score -1):

To set the default timezone for your entire Angular application, you can use the `LOCALE_ID` provider along with the `APP_INITIALIZER` in Angular. Here's an example:

1. Import necessary modules in your `app.module.ts`:

```js
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-US' }, // Set the default locale to 'en-US'
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApp,
      multi: true,
      deps: [LOCALE_ID]
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2. Create your `initializeApp` function in a separate file or within your `app.module.ts`:

```js
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

export function initializeApp(locale: string) {
  return async () => {
    try {
      await import(`@angular/common/locales/${locale}.js`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error loading locale data for ${locale}`, error);
    }
  };
}
```

3. Adjust your `main.ts` file to use the locale from the `LOCALE_ID` provider:

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
    providers: [
      { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-US' } // Set the default locale to 'en-US'
    ]
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

In this example, the default locale is set to 'en-US', but you can change it to 'en-GB', 'fr-FR', or any other supported locale. The `initializeApp` function is used to load locale data dynamically.

Make sure to adjust the timezone and locale according to your requirements.